# How to create Cron Job Command used for Renaming Multiple Filenames?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

How to create Cron Job Command used for Renaming Multiple Filenames?

I am a newbie to scripting and cron job commands. I have four files on my server at pathway `/public_html/mycommunicationcard`.

They are named `index.php`, `index2.php`, `zindex.php`, and `zindex2.php`.
I can use the user interface on my server to set the frequency of the cron job, but I need to write a cron command to rename these files from `index.php` to `xindex.php` and `index2.php` to `xindex2.php`.

I know about rename function but as per my understanding, it only works for renaming one file only at a time.

Any help or guidance would be appreciable.

Comment: Cronjobs are meant to schedule tasks that will be repeated with a certain frequency. If you have only 2 files to rename, why don't you just rename them via ssh or ftp?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from writing a bash scrip that renames multiple files. You would then schedule that script through cron.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that Cronjobs give you flexibilty in the scheduling of tasks or frequent requests you would like to automate. I suggest you write a bash script that will look like the one below :

```
#!bin/bash 
cd /public_html/mycommunicationcard
mv index.php xindex.php
mv index2.php xindex2.php
mv zindex.php xzindex.php
mv zindex2.php xzindex2php
```

You can schedule this in your cronjob to do the renaming of the files 
Assuming you save the above script as `rename.sh`
You can schedule with the below example :

```
* * * * * /public_html/mycommunicationcard/rename.sh
```

This will run at every minute to rename the files. Alternatively

```
* 1 * * * /public_html/mycommunicationcard/rename.sh
```

This will run every hour to update your files. The cron utility is very flexible and will require you to test to see which will best work for you.

Bonus https://crontab.guru/ is a good website to know the frequency of your requests